# How to add two view with didMoveToParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app, and depending on two separate and disparate events, I show a couple of views (views each have their own viewcontrollers). I am currently using addChildViewController/didMoveToParentViewController to show both the views.

ReceiptView: is a receipt (takes up 90% of the entire window)

OpeningMenu: is a normal selection menu (takes up 50% of entire window)

The issue I am having is that sometimes both are shown at the same time.

Option1: I would like to use addChildViewController/didMoveToParentViewController, as I am now, but make sure OpeningMenu is always underneath ReceiptView. Is it possible to add childviewController to a certain hierarchy?

Comment: You can set hierarchy of the views you add:  [self.yourContainerView insertSubview:OpeningMenu belowSubview:ReceiptView];  Anyway, it would be useful to see some of your code.

Comment: As above, you can manage view hierarchy separately from the view controller hierarchy.